# App has not responded to the network requests below : while running the detox test ( Detox + Jest )

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, jestjs, detox

My Setup

detox : 18.0.0
jest : 26.6.3
react-native-cli : 2.0.1
nodejs : 14.15.4
npm  : 6.14.10
yarn : 1.22.10
OS   : ubuntu 18.04
real connected device : Samsung M 01

[Please find the image on below url , after initialise the app by detox its not loading properly and this error screen is coming on connected device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7w22.png)

```
My init.js 

const detox = require('detox');
const adapter = require('detox/runners/jest/adapter');
const specReporter = require('detox/runners/jest/specReporter');

// Set the default timeout
jest.setTimeout(2000);

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(adapter);`enter code he`enter code here`re`

// This takes care of generating status logs on a per-spec basis. By default, jest only reports at file-level.
// This is strictly optional.
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(specReporter);

beforeAll(async () => {
  await detox.init();
  device.launchApp();
}, 300000);

beforeEach(async () => {
  try {
    await adapter.beforeEach();
  } catch (err) {
    // Workaround for the 'jest-jasmine' runner (default one): if 'beforeAll' hook above fails with a timeout,
    // unfortunately, 'jest' might continue running other hooks and test suites. To prevent that behavior,
    // adapter.beforeEach() will throw if detox.init() is still running; that allows us to run detox.cleanup()
    // in that emergency case and disable calling 'device', 'element', 'expect', 'by' and other Detox globals.
    // If you switch to 'jest-circus' runner, you can omit this try-catch workaround at all.

    await detox.cleanup();
    throw err;
  }
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await adapter.afterAll();
  await detox.cleanup();
});




My Package.json :


  "detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "android.emu.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
        "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
        "type": "android.attached",
        "device": {
          "adbName":"R9BN90441KJ"
        }
      },
      "android.emu.release": {
        "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk",
        "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release && cd ..",
        "type": "android.emulator",
        "name": "Test Kirana"
      }
    },
    "specs": "e2e",
    "test-runner": "jest"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
    ]
  }
```

Please find Error messages below :

detox[10532] WARN:  [Client.js/PENDING_REQUESTS] App has not responded to the network requests below:

HINT: Most likely, your tests have timed out and called detox.cleanup() while it was waiting for "ready" message (over WebSocket) from the instrumentation process.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

detox[10520] ERROR: [cli.js] Error: Command failed: jest --config e2e/config.json --testNamePattern '^((?!:ios:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 e2e/01-placeorder_from_all_page.spec.js